# Error with Encrypting Device with Veracrypt

Tags: macos, partitioning, security, encryption, veracrypt

I am trying to encrypt a 128GB USB Drive. I get the error "Formatting the device might cause system instability and/or data corruption. Please either select a partition on the device, or remove all partitions on the device to enable VeraCrypt to format it safely." when creating the drive.

I have formatted the drive with MBR and exFAT under macOS Disk Utility.

Could someone please point me in the right direction for correctly encrypting the entire drive so there would be no possibility of extraneous partition data leakage?

Comment: You can just create a Veracrypt container file that is as large as the drive itself. The encrypted partition will then be placed in that container and outside only this one encrypted file will be visible unless you mount the container via verycrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Do you talk about this message ?
[image: Veracrypt warning message for non-empty drive]

If yes, this is the message that Veracrypt displays when you try to encrypt a full drive that already contains partition.

If you try to encrypt a drive with no partition (i.e. only unallocated space), you won't get this message.
If you try to encrypt a partition, you won't get this message. You will however probably get this one :

[image: Veracrypt warning message]

It is usually wise to listen for warning messages :) And these are more than relevant as Veracrypt formats the drives by writing random data on them by default. This means that any data on a partition formatted by mistake is unrecoverable.

So you can rather create a file on a partition (as suggested by Robert), or make the whole space on your drive unallocated first, or go for a partition encryption. If you choose one of the latter, be careful, you will lose definitely all their content.